# Prompt Approver for information to import into SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, approval-process

I have a SharePoint List for SW Approval that requires two sets of approvals.

Current Flow is:

User Submits Request --> Request Sent to SW Eng for Approval --> Request Sent to Test Eng for Approval

I have a Flow that is triggered when the Request Status (Custom Col) is set to Review that sends an approval request to the SW Eng then upon approval will send an approval request to the Test Eng.

My question is regarding information that i would like to gather from the SW Eng and Test Eng at the time of approval. Is there a way to solicit information to be populated into the SharePoint List item under review at the time of Approval (via Email Notification)?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses and multiple methods to solicit the information to input into the SP List!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a flow to do the approval, the easiest option will be adding a `update a list item` action after the approval action to update the required field with the available dynamic content from the approval. You may need to use `Get items` action to get the required one.

Some of the available content from approval

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if, instead of using an approval flow, the action of flipping the status request to Review, sent an email with a link to a Form. The SW Eng could then fill in a few items including marking an SW Eng column as Approved, which would trigger an email to the Test Eng with a link to a Test Eng Form to fill out, which would also include the final approved column.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Power Automate (Flow) to get the "Approver's Comment" and update the SharePoint Item into the column where you want it to be stored.